# Is there a better way to hold a file path than in a string?

Tags: c#, path

I am making a command line utility.  I need to pass around a few file paths in the program.

Right now I am just using `string`.  But I was wondering if the .net library had a cool class for passing around file paths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings are the best way to store paths.

If you need to modify or work with the path, though, you should use **[System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_members.aspx)**.

If you want something that is a little more robust and can actually interact with files/directories you could also check out **[FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_members.aspx)** and **[DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo_members.aspx)**. Keep in mind, though, that both of these are awfully heavy if you just need to store the path.

Comment: Are they heavy? What's the overhead?

Comment: The overhead is that instead of a simple string, you have a big ol' object with a number of member fields that take up memory.  There is also the cost of object creation.  The constructor, especially, includes a number of expensive calls, some of which call outside of the .NET framework and might even result in disk I/O.

Answer (score 8):

Well, there's [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) - that's about as close as you get.

Comment: I used FileInfo in some previous projects, it's really nice, if you just want to read a file, use a string, If you want to manage files, folders and do some actions with them, use FileInfo

Answer (score 3):

The Base Class Library represents paths as strings but there are open source alternatives.
[NDepend.Helpers.FileDirectoryPath](https://github.com/psmacchia/NDepend.Path) is a open source library for manipulating paths in a strongly typed way.

Answer (score 0):

DirectoryInfo objects can hold filepaths and any relevant information about the directory, FileInfo can hold information and path of individual files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Justin Niessner answer is very good... but just to add on that:
System.Io.Path also has some static methods that can help, so we don't have to worry about extra "slashes" and cross-platform differences (back/forward slash for example).

Ex.: you can use .Join (or .Combine):

```
var readFile = new StreamReader(Path.Join(filePath, inputFileName));
```